# Is it existing better way to create user and password with salt tools

Tags: python, suse

Here my salt dependencies and system version :

```
#~: salt -V
Salt Version:
           Salt: 3000

Dependency Versions:
           cffi: 1.11.5
       cherrypy: Not Installed
       dateutil: Not Installed
      docker-py: Not Installed
          gitdb: Not Installed
      gitpython: Not Installed
         Jinja2: 2.8
        libgit2: Not Installed
       M2Crypto: 0.29.0
           Mako: Not Installed
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   mysql-python: Not Installed
      pycparser: 2.10
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
   pycryptodome: Not Installed
         pygit2: Not Installed
         Python: 2.7.18 (default, Apr 27 2020, 21:31:03) [GCC]
   python-gnupg: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 5.3.1
          PyZMQ: 14.0.0
          smmap: Not Installed
        timelib: Not Installed
        Tornado: 4.5.3
            ZMQ: 4.0.4

System Versions:
           dist: SuSE 12 x86_64
         locale: UTF-8
        machine: x86_64
        release: 4.12.14-122.136-default
         system: Linux
        version: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server  12 x86_64
```

I'm creating mass user list with salt using a hostname list like this :

```
for i in $(cat hostname_list.txt); do salt $i cmd.run "useradd -u 4441  -c \"John Doe \" -g 5900 -m jdoe" ; done ;
```

This kind of commande didn't create the password associate with user login

I tried this command for create the password but it's didn't work :

```
for i in $(cat hostname_list.txt); do salt $i user.passwd jdoe '<new Password>' ; done ;
```

I bypassed my issue in setting the password on one host first for grep the encrypted password in the /etc/shadow file and populate it :

```
for i in $(cat hostname_list.txt); do salt $i shadow.set_password jdoe 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Is there a solution with out grep the encrypted password.

Comment: Why are you using `cmd.run` module to create users instead of the `user.present` state?  There is no `user.passwd` salt module in the standard release so not sure where you got that from.  Why not use the `user.present` state to set the password from pillar or some other data source?  Also it seems odd you are using a file for hosts instead of salt's built in host selection mechanisms.

Comment: It's not false. I thought it was easiest and quicker way than creating a state file for each user inside file_roots. And more it's not secure as the password still clear in the state file. An other point,  I can not use salt with a host list set after the salt command. I had to create a file with the host listing. It's not normal too.

Answer (score 0):

That's working with the chpasswd tool

```
for i in $(cat hostname_list.txt); do salt $i cmd.run "echo 'jdoe:XXXXXXXX' | chpasswd" ; done ;
```